# HTTP PostJsonAsync is not working with Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a WebAPI post method:

```
[HttpPost]
public  void Submit(ICollection<IFormFile> formFiles)
{
   foreach (var formFile in formFiles)
   {
      if (formFile.Length > 0)
      {
         using (var stream = new FileStream(@"1.txt", FileMode.Create))
         {
            formFile.CopyTo(stream);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

From Client I am trying to do :

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

CustomFormFile fromFile = new CustomFormFile(new FileInfo("ds.txt"));
ICollection<IFormFile> listFormsFiles = new List<IFormFile>();

listFormsFiles.Add(fromFile);         

var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(requestURL, listFormsFiles)
```

When I am trying to set a breakpoint on my WebApi it is not getting hit, but if I change the PostAsync to following, breakpoint gets hit:

```
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(requestURL, fromFile);
```

But on service, this becomes `null` as it was expecting a list but got a single object.

Any pointers what am I missing?

Comment: Try `Request.Form.Files` property inside `Submit` action.

Comment: accordingly to documentation looks like you need to use `IEnumerable<IFormFile>` (or `List<IFormFile>`)